# How can I update this SELECT query to use an age range

Tags: mysql

**Looking for:**

I want to add some functionality to this select query. Right now the query selects users based on there genre and status. (Ignore the status part, it is on another table as you can see.) I want to add an age range to this selector, something like this if age > 18 && < 27. Both of this information can be find on the user table.

**Current query:**

```
SELECT 
    u.*
FROM
    User u
        LEFT JOIN
    User_Status us ON u.id = User_ID1 AND us.User_ID2 = 4
WHERE
    gender = 'f'
        AND (us.Status != 'FRIENDS'
        OR us.status IS NULL)
```

**Wanted result:**

Same query with the addition of the age range selector.

**User table:**

ID - Int
first_name - char
last_name - 
email - varchar
password - char
***birthday - date***

gender - char
looking_for_gender - char
***minimum_age - int

maximum_age - int***

maximim_distance - int
pictures - varchar
biography - varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `age` of a user would be derived from `birthday` and the current date.

Conversely, given an "age range", we can determine a lower bound and upper bound for `birthday`.

For example, users with an age of 25 would have birthday in the range:

```
  WHERE u.birthday >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 25 YEAR - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
    AND u.birthday <  DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 25 YEAR
```

Users with ages in the range 18 to 27 would have birthday in the range:

```
  WHERE u.birthday >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 27 YEAR - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
    AND u.birthday <  DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 18 YEAR
```

---

We can test our expressions in a SELECT statement

```
 SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 27 YEAR - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AS lower_bound 
      , DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 18 YEAR                   AS upper_bound
```

returns:

```
 lower_bound  upper_bound
 -----------  -----------
 1989-04-03   1999-04-03
```

A user with a birthday *after* 1999-04-03 is *under* 18 years of age.

A user with a birthday *before* 1989-04-03 is *older* than 27.

We'd need to decide how to handle the edge case of the equality condition. Do we want to use `<=` or `<`, and do we want to use `>=` or `>`.

Comment: This is the correct answer if age is stored as a date.